# Recurring Orders App Crash with Editify App Shopify

Tags: php, heroku, recurring-billing, shopify-app

I've developed a recurring orders (i.e.order subscription) app to shopify store.

With the presence of Editify App it crashes and creates same root order + recurred orders for indefinite amount of time.

Does anybody has any solution? Thanks in advance!